# Python TKinter : Manually Trigger a Bind Event (Specifically Configure)

Tags: python, tkinter, events

I'm busy working with a TKinter GUI and am trying to append additional Items into a Scrollbar Canvas. The scrollbar bits seem to be working just fine

```
def canvas_configure(self, event):
    self.canvas.configure(scrollregion=self.canvas.bbox("all"))
canvas.bind("<Configure>", lambda event: self.canvas_configure(event))
```

The configure function triggers on resizes just fine but does not trigger when appending Items, I was wondering if it's possible to manually trigger the `<Configure>` (or other events for that matter)

```
def append_to_canvas(self, parent):
    label = tk.Label(parent, text="Yes")
    label.pack();
    # canvas execute <Configure>
```

*NOTE*

The way I handle situations like this at the moment is to just execute the same function that the event would be executing, for example

```
def append_to_canvas(self, parent):
    label = tk.Label(parent, text="Yes")
    label.pack()
    event = # create imposter event here
    self.canvas_configure(event)
```

But this isn't always practical

*CLARITY*

The example I'm using above is just an example. I'm more concerned with the Manual Triggering of a Bind Event part of the question.

This applies to other bind events such as

```
button.bind("<Button-1>", lambda event: exec_button_click());
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Your description is incomplete. It's unclear why you are having a problem. You bind to `<Configure>` when the widget resizes so  you can adjust the scrollbar. The event will _always_ fire if the widget changes size. If it doesn't fire, the size didn't change, and therefore you shouldn't need to adjust the scrollbar.

Comment: @BryanOakley, the question is more of a general "how to fire a bound event", I don't really want to distract people from the point with my ugly ass code. I'll try make it more clear in the question though

Comment: _"But this isn't always practical"_ - why isn't it always practical?

Comment: A lot of the events have an `event` parameter that has to be recreated manually

Comment: If your code doesn't use the event, you don't need to create one. Yes, it is impractical in some cases, but in this case, your callback isn't using the event object.

Comment: In this case it doesn't need the event but it's still a lot easier to just trigger the event instead of doing it manually, only maintain a single function call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I've found out how to do this, it looks like there's a function for this feature called `event_generate`

```
self.canvas.event_generate("<Configure>");
```

Comment: But still, the canvas is not resizing in all cases.

Comment: Wait it isn't? Is there a case I've forgotten about?

Comment: It does solve my problem though, this is literally all I wanted

Comment: Successfully populated text fields on form load by firing the `ttk_combobox.event_generate('<<ComboboxSelected>>')` that evoked the bound `on_select` function. I can't imagine why `ttk_combobox.current(0)`  does not trigger this event.